# I cannot acces from my master Kubernetes cluster to a pod

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubectl

If I have a set of deployments that are connected using a NetworkPolicy ingress. It's work! However, if I have to connect from outside (IP got from kubectl get ep), I have to set another ingress to the endpoint? or egress policy?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: nginx
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: ./kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.22.0 (955b78124)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: nginx
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: ./kompose convert
        kompose.version: 1.22.0 (955b78124)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.network/nginx: "true"
        io.kompose.service: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: nginx
          name: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
          resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: mariadb
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: ./kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.22.0 (955b78124)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: mariadb
  name: mariadb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: mariadb
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: ./kompose convert
        kompose.version: 1.22.0 (955b78124)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.network/nginx: "true"
        io.kompose.service: mariadb
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: mariadb
          name: mariadb
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
...
```

You can see more code here http://pastie.org/p/2QpNHjFdAK9xj7SYuZvGPf

Endpoints:

```
kubectl get ep -n nginx
NAME       ENDPOINTS             AGE
mariadb  192.168.112.203:5432  2d2h
nginx     192.168.112.204:8000  42h
```

Services:

```
NAME       TYPE       CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP  PORT(S)         AGE
mariadb ClusterIP  10.99.76.78    <none>       5432/TCP        2d2h
nginx     NodePort   10.111.176.21  <none>       8000:31604/TCP  42h
```

Tests from server:

```
If I do curl 10.111.176.21:31604 -- No answer
If I do curl 192.168.112.204:8000 -- No answer
If I do curl 192.168.112.204:31604 -- No answer
If I do curl 10.0.0.2:8000 or 31604 -- No answer
10.0.0.2 is a worker node IP.
```

**UPDATED** If I do `kubectl port-forward nginx-PODXXX 8000:8000`
I can access it from HTTP://localhost:8000

So What's I am wrong in on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using the [Network Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) *as* an ingress for incoming traffic, but what you probably want to be using is an [Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) to manage [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) traffic.

Egress is for traffic flowing outbound from your services within your cluster to external sources. Ingress is for external traffic to be directed to specific services within your cluster.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-app-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: my-example.site.tld
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: nginx
              servicePort: 5432
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.

But, What happens if I have an internal cluster? Did I set host: directive domain too redirected by load balancer?

Why is not possible to get the connections of the pod to the outside if It exposed?

Comment: Can you define what an internal cluster is in this case? You can always direct traffic from a cloud load balancer or VIP to the workers running ingress controllers on your cluster, and then an ingress defines where that traffic is routed. This is how you expose an internal service/app to the outside world. Pod -> Service -> Ingress.